# Add button in listview with externe layout

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I have created a listview with externe layout like tweet and I want to set button clickable into all of the adapter like the X in photo:

[image]

Example when I click in button if I'm admin I delete the post

This is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);

    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listItem = new ArrayList<>();

    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    map.put("module", "Example");
    map.put("years", "Year");
    map.put("sections", "Section");
    map.put("groupe", "Groupe");
    map.put("urlImage",("Image"));
    map.put("date","example");


    listItem.add(map);

    SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter
        (getBaseContext(), listItem, R.layout.affichage,
                new String[]{"avatar", "module", "years", "sections", "groupe"},
                new int[]{R.id.avatar, R.id.module, R.id.years, R.id.sections, R.id.groupe});



    ListView.setAdapter(mSchedule);
}
```

Comment: listItem.remove(position); any item remove from array

Comment: @KishanViramgama I want to remove from database firestore

Comment: means remove record in fire base database

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement CustomAdapter with BaseAdapter as base class. 
You can check this link https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-a-BaseAdapter-with-ListView for implementation details

Comment: No result, how to declare the button that is located on the external layout on the activity and then when I click on its button I launch a function

Comment: What do you mean by external layout ? Button will be part of adapter view layout. Depending on adapter item you show/hide close button